# Abstract Algebra books (for undergraduate)

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, modular-arithmetic, book-recommendation

I'm looking for good books of abstract algebra. In particular, I need some books with a lot of exercises, solved and not (in particular about modular arithmetic, groups and rings) Do you have any hints? Thanks.

Comment: How about Gallian's *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra"*?

Comment: There aren't going to really be any book-recommendation type questions on basic areas like abstract-algebra that aren't already covered by previous posts. Please take care to search first in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I remember enjoying Pinter's *A Book of Abstract Algebra* in undergrad.